# Bootstrap 3. Правильное позиционирование элементов

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, позиционирование

Как в *bootstrap* правильно прижать к правому краю кнопку (*"button"*), верстать через `<div>col*-*` и задавать `col-offset`? Или есть специальные *бутстраповские* классы для этого?

Comment: Есть класс `pull-right`. Будет что-то типа `<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-1 pull-right"><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></div></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Тут в одном вопросе сразу четыре вопроса.
Отвечаю на последний:

Специальные бутстраповские классы для этого есть.

Подробнее в документации http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы прижимать к правому углу, можно использовать один из классов  `pull-right` или `text-right`